# how to control the threads running within a process on android platform

Tags: java, android, multithreading, testing, adb

Is there any way/tool to control the threads running within a process on android platform, such as let some threads delay for a random time.

 
Background: I am a QA engineer. I'd like to see if some threads are forced to run slowly, what will happen to the whole app? I'd like to see other kind of errors rather than ANR. For multiple threading, if programmer doesn't use or use bad strategies to sync threads, some bugs might happen. So I want to do this kind of testing.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to take care of the UIThread, well actually Android will take care of it for you. Taking that into account, try to don't do any intensive operation in this thread as you won't have full control of it (see [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html))

As long as the UIthread is fine, you won't notice a slow responding app, for the rest of threads I suggest you taking a look in different classes that will ease the task of communicating back with this UIThread;
[Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) & [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), there are more options, but these two are the most important (imo)

The rest of threads, you can control them as you would in Java, even sleeping them if needed.

Let's see an example:

```
public class MapView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
   Thread t = null;
   SurfaceHolder holder;
   boolean draw = false;


@Override
public void run() {
   while (draw) {
   if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
   continue;

    Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
    //Draw something
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


void pause() {
 draw = false;
try {
        t.join(); // this will cause the main thread to wait for this one to  
        //finish and then it can safely access its data.
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    t = null;
  }

  void resume() {
       draw = true;
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start(); // This will look for our run method (this)
 }

}
```

In this example,  a normal Thread is used to control how/when and with what delay we draw. The resume and pause methods let us control that thread so we can stop drawing if the activity using it is in background and restart it when it comes back (Overriding onPause and onResume)

Comment: could you give more details about you mentioned the rest of threads, how to control them in Java? Thanks.